# syntax error at or near "WHERE" in findOne (typeorm - nestjs)

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Error in findOne() (getPhonById)
Full error in following images:

Error screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ4nk.jpg

Tried deleting table and creating new, tried using find() but same question.

code in screenshots above

expected 1 record from db

Comment: Please [don't post code as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, I've replicated it only difference being that i use mySQL and it works. You can add a line to your typeorm.config.ts file: logging: true,
it will output your query to the console and then you can see what's wrong with it.